# The type Part is ambiguous

Tags: java, html, jsp, web, web-deployment

I'm working on small project where I'm trying to dd profile so the user can upload his profile pic so while I was searching for references I found some Youtube videos and I started coding and I want to link the image which user uploaded as his profile image.
There I'm getting the error "The type Part is ambiguous"(in jsp)

```
<%@page 
 import="java.sql.*,java.text.*,javax.servlet.*,java.security.MessageDigest,
   java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException 
      ,javax.mail.*,javax.mail.internet.*,
       java.io.File,java.io.PrintWriter,java.awt.List"%> 

     <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%!
    %>
    <%
    String username=(String) session.getAttribute("nkey");
    String f_name =request.getParameter("f_name");
    String l_name =request.getParameter("l_name");

    Part part =request.getPart("profile_link");(here I'm getting the issue)
    String id_link =request.getParameter("id_link");
    String age =request.getParameter("age");
    String gender =request.getParameter("gender");
    String address =request.getParameter("address");
    String pincode =request.getParameter("pincode");
    String qualification =request.getParameter("qualification");
    String year =request.getParameter("year");
    String college_name =request.getParameter("college_name");
    String state =request.getParameter("state");
    String country =request.getParameter("country");
    %>
    <%!
    private static final String SAVE_DIR="Pictures";
    %>
    <%response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");%>
    <% 
    PrintWriter outt=response.getWriter();
    String savePath="C:/Users/thots/Desktop/My World/internsip/Student_Portal 2.0/WebContent"+File.separator+SAVE_DIR;
    File fileSaveDir=new File(savePath);

    String fileName=extractFileName(part);
    
    part.write(savePath + File.separator + fileName);
    
    String filePath=savePath+File.separator + fileName;     
    %>
    <%
    try 
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Student_Portal 2.0","root","");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        int i=st.executeUpdate("insert into student_details values('"+username+"','"+f_name+"','"+l_name+"','"+filePath+"','"+id_link+"','"+age+"','"+gender+"','"+address+"','"+pincode+"','"+qualification+"','"+year+"','"+college_name+"','"+state+"','"+country+"')");
        if(i>0)
        {
            response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
            Statement stt=con.createStatement();
            String sql="update user_login set P_Status='1' where username='"+username+"'";
            stt.executeUpdate(sql);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Failed");
        }

    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    %>
```

Html code

```
<form action="add_student_details.jsp" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div>
                                    <label for="img">Upload Profile Picture</label>
                                     <input name="profile_link" type="file" class="form-control" required>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div>
                                    <label for="img">Upload Your ID card</label>
                                    <input name="id_link" type="file" class="form-control" required>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-6">
                                     <input name="f_name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-6">
                                    <input name="l_name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-6">
                                     <input name="age" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Age" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-6">
                                      <select name="gender" class="form-control" required>
                                        <option>Male</option>
                                        <option >Female</option>
                                      </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div>
                                <textarea name="address" rows="4" cols="55" placeholder="Your Address" id="w3review" required></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div>
                                <input name="pincode" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Pincode" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                        <br>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                         <h4>Educational Info</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                          <select name="qualification" class="form-control" required>
                                          <option selected disabled>Select Your Qualification</option>
                                            <option>B.Tech</option>
                                            <option >B.E</option>
                                          </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                          <select name="year" class="form-control" required>
                                          <option selected disabled>Select Your Year</option>
                                            <option>I</option>
                                            <option >II</option>
                                            <option>III</option>
                                            <option >IV</option>
                                          </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                                <div >
                                          <select name="college_name" class="form-control" required>
                                          <option selected disabled>Select Your College</option>
                                            <option>ABCD College Of Engineering And Technology</option>
                                            <option >XYZ College Of Engineering And Technology</option>
                                          </select>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                          <select name="state" class="form-control" required>
                                          <option selected disabled>Select Your State</option>
                                            <option>Telangana</option>
                                            <option >Kerala</option>
                                          </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                          <select name="country" class="form-control" required>
                                          <option selected disabled>Select Your Country</option>
                                            <option>India</option>
                                            <option>United States</option>
                                          </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                                <hr>
                                <center>
                                <button type="submit" class="submit-btn">Submit</button>
                                </center>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                       </form>
```

Sorry for sharing the whole code.
i tried multiple ways but none worked for me
someone please help me
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means that the compiler can resolve the type `Part` to more than one class available in the packages you're importing (or a name conflict with a one of your custom classes that also happen to be named `Part`).

In your specific case, you're importing two packages, each of which includes a class named `Part`.

```
javax.servlet.http.Part
javax.mail.Part
```

To avoid this error, you can use the full namespace for the class like this:

```
javax.servlet.http.Part part =request.getPart("profile_link");
```

Best practice, however, is to avoid importing entire packages when you're only using specific classes from those packages whenever possible.

Do not:

```
import java.servlet.*;
```

Do:

```
import java.servlet.http.Part;
```

Comment: hi sir
now im getting an error("The method extractFileName(Part) is undefined for the type 
__2F_Student_5F_Portal_20_2_2E_0_2F_WebContent_2F_add_5F_student_5F_details_2E_jsp")    at the line                                                                                           
 String fileName=extractFileName(part);   same code i did use this to resolve previous issue javax.servlet.http.Part part =request.getPart("profile_link");                                            added these to header files(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.Paths,javax.servlet.http.Part)
Thank you

Comment: Now you're asking another question. Stack Overflow uses a question and answer format. You post one question, you get one answer. If the answer solves your problem, you accept it and post any new questions separately. Don't edit your original question to ask new questions either -- doing so only confuses people who search for the same issue and find that the answers have nothing to do with the question because the question has been changed.

Comment: Just to get you started, it looks like you're trying to call extractFileName() on a String literal, rather than on some object which should be implementing the extractFileName method. That method is probably from a class you wrote yourself.

Comment: Yes, but you're calling extractFileName without specifying an instance of an object which has that method. It looks like you're calling it as if the JSP page itself should be implementing that method -- are you sure that's right? You should really post a second question, because I think the answer might be more involved than you imagine, and because I haven't written JSP in some time.